# Thunderbird Automatically Get (POP) New Mail, Via the OS (Mac OS X)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, email, thunderbird, pop3

I want the OS to check for new mail using my POP account in thunderbird without having to manually start thunderbird (its ok if thunderbird automatically starts as a windowed process and doesn't just run in the background).

Like explained [here](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/back_your_gmail?page=0%2C1) except using thunderbird not Mail. I was unable to find the proper automator action to do this.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not the OS exactly, but [MacBiff](http://macbiff.sourceforge.net/) is pretty light-weight, runs in your menu bar and checks for new mail periodically.  It can alert you audibly, by running another app (Tbird, maybe?), or with Growl.

Comment: It looks good, but it doesn't seem to support POP.

Comment: Oops - you're right.  The only POP checker I could find is http://www.popmonitor.com/index.html .  Might be a little old though.